# Double axis Y in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

i want to ask for some questions about chart.js. I have been create my dashboard with chart.js for showing my database on user interface, but. I have a little bug on Axis Y in chart.js, like double category. This is my dashboard picture
[none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vaKq.png)
And this my syntax.

```
<script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        
        var chartData = {}; // Menyiapkan objek untuk menyimpan data chart

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar', // Menggunakan chart jenis bar
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Statistik Karyawan',
                    data: [],
                    backgroundColor: ['skyblue'], // Warna untuk masing-masing kategori
                    borderWidth: 1
                }],
                labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Agu', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Des']
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: false,
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                // Menampilkan label kategori sesuai index
                                return getCategoryLabel(value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                responsive: true, // Membuat chart responsif
                maintainAspectRatio: true // Mengatur rasio aspek chart
            }
        });

        // Fungsi untuk mendapatkan label kategori
        function getCategoryLabel(value) {
            // Menentukan label kategori sesuai nilai
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 1) {
                return 'Ringan';
            } else if (value >= 2 && value <= 3) {
                return 'Sedang';
            } else if (value >= 4) {
                return 'Berat';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }

        // Fungsi untuk mengupdate chart dengan data baru
        function updateChart(newData) {
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data = newData.allData;
            myChart.update();
        }

        // Fungsi untuk mengubah data chart saat terjadi perubahan
        function onDataChanged() {
            var newData = {
                allData: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
            };

            // Menggunakan objek untuk melacak kategori yang sudah ditambahkan
            var addedCategories = {};

            // Memproses data baru dan menambahkannya ke chart
            newData.allData.forEach(function(value) {
                var categoryLabel = getCategoryLabel(value);

                // Menambahkan kategori ke chart hanya jika belum ada
                if (!addedCategories[categoryLabel]) {
                    addedCategories[categoryLabel] = true;
                    myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(value);
                }
            });

            updateChart(newData);
        }

        onDataChanged();
    </script>
```

I'm so confused about this bug, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question (double-axis Y little bug) correctly, you have "double-category" in the y-axis because you have specified the following

```
 ticks: {
         callback: function(value, index, values) {
         // Menampilkan label kategori sesuai index
         return getCategoryLabel(value);
                            }
                        }
```

but the getCategoryLabel function return is like this (returning the same values multiple times):

```
function getCategoryLabel(value) {
            // Menentukan label kategori sesuai nilai
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 1) {
                return 'Ringan';
            } else if (value >= 2 && value <= 3) {
                return 'Sedang';
            } else if (value >= 4) {
                return 'Berat';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
```

If you wish the Y-axis to show the numeric value instead, simply remove (or remark) the ticks block as follows:

```
/*   
ticks: {
         callback: function(value, index, values) {
         // Menampilkan label kategori sesuai index
         return getCategoryLabel(value);
                            }
                        }

                   */
```

On the other hand, you have not set the following

```
beginAtZero: true,
```

So the following sample code will have the result (see picture underneath)

```
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>


<script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        
        var chartData = {}; // Menyiapkan objek untuk menyimpan data chart

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar', // Menggunakan chart jenis bar
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Statistik Karyawan',
                    data: [],
                    backgroundColor: ['skyblue'], // Warna untuk masing-masing kategori
                    borderWidth: 1
                }],
                labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Agu', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Des']
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    /*   
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                // Menampilkan label kategori sesuai index
                                return getCategoryLabel(value);
                            }
                        }
                   */

                    }

                },
                responsive: true, // Membuat chart responsif
                maintainAspectRatio: true // Mengatur rasio aspek chart
            }
        });

        // Fungsi untuk mendapatkan label kategori
        function getCategoryLabel(value) {
            // Menentukan label kategori sesuai nilai
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 1) {
                return 'Ringan';
            } else if (value >= 2 && value <= 3) {
                return 'Sedang';
            } else if (value >= 4) {
                return 'Berat';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }

        // Fungsi untuk mengupdate chart dengan data baru
        function updateChart(newData) {
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data = newData.allData;
            myChart.update();
        }

        // Fungsi untuk mengubah data chart saat terjadi perubahan
        function onDataChanged() {
            var newData = {
                allData: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
            };

            // Menggunakan objek untuk melacak kategori yang sudah ditambahkan
            var addedCategories = {};

            // Memproses data baru dan menambahkannya ke chart
            newData.allData.forEach(function(value) {
                var categoryLabel = getCategoryLabel(value);

                // Menambahkan kategori ke chart hanya jika belum ada
                if (!addedCategories[categoryLabel]) {
                    addedCategories[categoryLabel] = true;
                    myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(value);
                }
            });

            updateChart(newData);
        }

        onDataChanged();
    </script>
```

[image]